# closing parent form from child form

Tags: c#, forms, parent

I have a problem with my forms. I have a parent and child form. In child form I have a button. I want to close parent window using button and create new instance parent form and shows new parent form. 
Anyone can help me?
I tried

```
private Form1 m_parent;

        public Form2(Form1 frm1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            m_parent = frm1;
        }
```

and 
after that m_parent.Close(), but only what I got is both forms was closed and this is it. After m_parent i create new instance but my application was closed.

Comment: Q: What have you tried so far?  Q: Who is the parent window's parent?  Is there some "main form" that can receive a message to "open a new form"?  Or will your program actually exit when you close the form?

Comment: I tried so far. Owner.Close and this.ParentForm but without result

Comment: do not use this.parentform I think you can close it using parent ref

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[calling parent functions from child form](http://forum.codecall.net/c-programming/515-c-calling-parent-functions-child-form.html)

```
Main frm = new Main();
frm.Show();
frm.Activate();
this.Hide();
```

This will hide the current form and shows Main form.

Comment: But that's not what you originally asked: "I want to close parent window using button and create new instance parent form"

Answer (score 0):

You can get a ref from parent in child and then use close method of parent.